# Dumbbell Scaption vs iron cross on rings

Tags: dumbbells, shoulders, gymnastics

First, for reference, a [dumbbell scaption](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/dumbbell-scaption):

[image: http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/exerciseImages/sequences/1341/Male/m/1341_2.jpg]

An iron cross on the rings:

[image]

My question is... if someone weighs 140lbs and can do an iron cross is that the equivalent of doing a dumbbell scaption with 70lbs dumbbell's in both hands?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not well formulated and blatantly ignores the laws of physics.

Comment: What is the purpose of asking this question...?

Comment: _"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."_ [[Help: Don't ask](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)]

Answer (score 7):

No. Different moves are different.

Most notably, holding dumbbells *up* is not the same as pushing *down* on rings.